# Retrieve more than 3 data's from mysql into checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

I need to retrieve the hobbies name from `mysql` and display it in check boxes. I done the below given code. But it displays just check box and not any hobby names. Please help.

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM hobbies";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, "$query");
 while ($r=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
    $hobby=$r["hobby_name"];?>
    <input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='$hobby'>
 }
```

Comment: Forget to `echo` at `$hobby=$r["hobby_name"];?>`

Comment: Checkbox is a box to be checked, it can contain a value but it wont display any sort of string, only a tick on it is applicable. You can display the value next to it as an identifier or something like that...done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add simple text `$hobby` next to every checkbox.

Corrected code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM hobbies";
$result = mysqli_query($con, "$query");
while ($r=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 $hobby=$r["hobby_name"];
?>
<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='<?php echo $hobby;?>'> <?php echo $hobby;?>
<?php
}
```

Comment: I had hobby_id in the same table hobbies.

Comment: But i need to store all the hobby_id whichever is selected in another table. Please provide the coding for this. I really don't have any idea.

Answer (score 1):

Checkbox input itself does not display any text. You need to show both checkbox and text separately like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='$hobby'><label>$hobby</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
     $query = "SELECT * FROM hobbies";
     $result = mysqli_query($con, "$query");
     while ($r=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
          $hobby=$r["hobby_name"];
          echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='".$hobby."'><label>".$hobby."</label>";
     }
?>
```